# How can I use the result from a function as a parameter to another function in C?

Tags: c, function, parameters

In a function that returns void and has no parameters I want to use two other functions (unfortunately I cannot modify that). The first of these functions calculates the result of an int and I want to pass that result as a parameter to the second function. How could I achieve that? thank you.

```
void descriptionEdit(void)
{
   while(1)
   {
      int fieldno;
      if (!pluFields())
      {
        break;
      }
      start_editor(setf, esize);
      do
      {
         //code
      } while(fieldno>=0);
      saveEditor();
   }
}


bool pluFields(void)
{
   **edplu** = search_productcode();
   if (edplu == 0)
   {
      return true;
   }
}

void saveEditor()
{
   if (save_plu(**edplu**, &plu))
   {
      CloseProductIniFile();
      cls();
      writeat(30, 6, INV2X3, "Save Confirmed");
   }
}
```

So, I want somehow to use the edplu from pluFields function as a parameter to saveEditor function, I thought to make edplu global variable but I think this is a bad practice

Comment: I guess this is pseudo code, but note that not all paths return a value in `pluFields`

Comment: also not sure how the code you posted is relevant to your question. I don't see a function that returns an `int` or a function that accepts an argument.

Comment: @yano yes, its pseudo code. Apologies for misunderstanding, what I was trying to say isa function that calculates an int and not returning an int, so I forgot to mention that the edplu is an int variable. As for the function that accepts an argument is the saveEditor function, so I wanted to pass the edplu inside that function and that's why I left it only with parenthesis

Comment: oh ok .. well glad you're squared away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You algorithm is very non-intuitive. However, to get a value of a function and pass to another function do this:

```
int functionName(int param1) { 
  // calculate values
  return variable_here
}

int value = functionName(param1)
```

then value will go onto the parameter of your next function, like that

```
void function2(int value) ...
function2(value)
```

Let me know if I helped.

Comment: this is what i was looking for, thank you very much!